# Does .Net have any built in constants for common numbers like million, billion etc?

Tags: .net, constants, literals

Does .Net have any built in constants for common numbers like million, billion etc?

EDIT: As has been suggested this was for readability reasons, rather than writing 1000000 or 1000000000. I know I can create my own just wanted to check that they didnt already exist before I did so.

Comment: Are you expecting the value of OneBillion to change?

Comment: Need the picture of the face of Dr Evil somewhere.

Comment: +1 @rexm Only if your server will travel between the US and the UK

Comment: Re: Rex M - no, but I am expecting to compare numbers to it in various places so using a constant would be more readable.

Comment: Perl allows _ as a blank character in numeric literals improving readability of large numbers quite a lot. I.e. OneMillion = 1_000_000 It's a feature I quite liked, especially with binary $x = 0b1100_0000;

Comment: There are at least a billion different ways to do this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can see your point where a manifest constant in code like 1000000000 might have a readability problem "is that one hundred million or a billion". However, I'd create a constant that suited the particular situation rather than a generic constant. For example

```
#define BANKOFAMERICA_TARP_AMOUNT 1000000000.0; // One billion dollars
```

Comment: that constant should be closer to 153000000000, according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubled_Asset_Relief_Program#Participants.  I'm going to go prepare for doomsday now.

Comment: excuse me, I did my math wrong.  That should have been 163000000000.  Note that this will not fit in a 32 bit integer.

Comment: When I said "Dollars" I meant "Gold Sovereigns", but I figured the reference might be a bit vague... :)

Comment: One *billion* dollars! <pinky>

Comment: +1 for "suited the particular situation", 
#define DEVELOPER_BILLION 1073741824 //2^30

Answer (score 23):

Sure, they are named 1e6, 1e9, etc... ;-)

Comment: Hey, I didn't know that. That's nice.

Comment: As with the other comment, while this is intended as a joke, you're listing *literals*, not *constants*.

Comment: @Adam: Sure, that's the point of the joke. :-) Thanks, though, for pointing it out, since this might not be obvious to everyone. @All: Note that the above literals return floating-point values, not integers.

Comment: why have we not thought about this earlier... shame on us!

Answer (score 8):

No. In general, constant values are best used for literals which have semantics outside of their value. For example, 3.14159 is a literal, but it's also a broadly important mathematical value, π (albeit an approximation).

By comparison, a number like 1,000,000 is simply a literal and doesn't necessarily have any general meaning other than its value, so there's not much worth in making it a built-in constant. In a particular application or context, however, it might be important -- perhaps 1,000,000 is the maximum number of `ShippingContainers` your tanker can hold or something similar. That's where you'd use a constant.

Comment: It's even more important to realize that numbers like million and billion only even have the *slightest* meaning in base-10.

Comment: 3.14159 is not π, it's merely an approximation within an error of around 2.7e-6.

Comment: @ Johannes, with pi, an approximation is all you can ever get.

Comment: @Gurdas: Depends on your programming language/library. It might be an interesting exercise to provide a precise "Pi" constant in a language that supports lazy evaluation of irrational numbers...

Comment: @Gurdas: going along with what @Heinzi said, if your language supports lazy evaluation and/or symbolic evaluation, it's entirely possible to create expressions where the πs cancel out and you're left with an exact result.

Comment: @Johannes: You are correct, of course. I was taking a little liberty with the specifics in an attempt to focus on what I thought was the central point: just because something is a literal doesn't mean it has any significance as a constant.

Comment: Okay, what is the exact value of pi, then? Oh, crap. We just used all the available atoms in the universe. Stack overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you think million and billion are common numbers?

Comment: @Si: *your* application, hence the need for you to define *your own* constants ;)

Answer (score 5):

No,

There are a few constant avallable, like

- double.Epsilon
- Math.PI

But not for million and billion.

You can create your own constants

```
public const int OneMillion = 1000000;
```

I presume you are looking to transform a number like `int value = 1000000` into a natural string like `string value = "1 million"`.

That don't exist in .NET by default, but it could be coded easily or I presume you could find such code on Google.

For example, you could create an extension method on `int` that transform the number into a human natural language string: *(this is cheap code from off the head)*

```
public static string ToNaturalString(this int value)
{
    if (value == 1000000)
        return "1 million";
    else
        return value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: A little correction: it *is* possible to format a number like that, by using one or more commas directly *after* the number placeholder. Each comma scales by 1000 and then the result is rounded: 1000000.ToString("0,, 'million'") == "1 million"; 1500000.ToString("0,, 'million'") == "2 million"

Comment: Its very sensitive to the current culture, so it is dangerous to rely on the comma although you could format into InvariantLanguage.

Comment: Specifically, remember that many cultures interchange the meaning of "." and "," in numbers.  Is 100,000 an integral hundred thousand or a floating-point hundred?  Depends on where you are.

Answer (score 3):

Even if there were such constant, the word "billion" means different things whether you're American or European.

In North America, a billion equals 1,000,000,000 = 10^9; in Europe, a billion equals 1,000,000,000,000 = 10^12.  (A milliard = 10^9.)

Comment: I don't know which bit of Europe you're referring to, but for everywhere I've been (including where I live in the UK) a billion is not 1,000,000,000,000! It's 1,000,000,000

Comment: @joshcomley:  List of long-scale countries listed here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#Current_usage

Comment: @Tenner - But I'm European! You can't just generalise and say "Europe", that is misleading and just wrong

Comment: @joshcomley:  Fair enough, but I was trying to put out a quick comment that got the general gist across in six characters instead of 600.  Sorry if I offended you.

Comment: @josh: Only a "European" would be offended by such a remark ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going with no.

There are built in constants for the largest and smallest number that will fit in an int or long, for example, but no arbitrary constants between those points.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite to use is:

```
public const float EleventyBillion = 110000000000;
```

Comment: Wouldn't eleventy billion be 110,000,000,000? What you listed was eleven billion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we could have one on the grounds that there is a difference between a US Billion (one hundred thousand million) and a British (and others?) Billion (one million million)

[Differences in short scale and long scale numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion)

Comment: Couldnt there be 2 constants for billion, with different names?

Comment: Yes, that's possible I suppose

Comment: As mentioned *in the link you provided* a US billion is one thousand million, not one hundred thousand million.

Comment: Consider me suitably admonished for posting first, finding a suitable article second

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat tongue-in-cheek, but there's nothing stopping you putting extension methods on `int`:

```
public static int million(this int i)
{
    return i * 1000000;
}
```

in order to make

```
 int approximatePopulationOfUnitedStates = 300.million();
```

valid code...

Comment: in a strange way, I really like that.

Comment: It's worse than that, it's 350.million()!

Comment: 300.Thousand().Million() == 300.Billion()

Comment: You could also add all sorts of other extensions, like `Tenths` and `Hundredths`. God save us.

Answer (score 1):

could do something neat like have a library class

```
public class One
{
  public const int Thousand = 1000;
  public const int Million = Thousand * Thousand;
  public const int Billion = Million * Million;
  ...
}
```

Then when you go to use it it looks a bit neater

```
int myNumber = 72 * One.Million;
```

I must admit, I do this sometimes just for purely readability (however just have consts at the top of a class, not a dedicated library).  Sometimes it's useful for numbers to have something like

```
// Add one to account for whatever
int countPlus1 = count + 1;
```

if you are referencing it a heap of times afterwards, it just makes code that little bit neater IMO.  Also makes commenting easier, as it's easier to put a short comment at the start to understand why you are adding one to the variable all the time than just see random `count + 1` code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
int million = 1000000;
int billion = 1000000000;
```

Just like `5`, `a`, and `-1`, these are constants.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I'd say there's nothing more constant than a literal.

Comment: double one = 1.5;

Assert.That(one + one == 3);
Q.E.D.

Comment: @Dinah: Death and taxes come to mind. Nonetheless, as terms of art "constant" and "literal" are different.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: since we're splitting hairs, technically we could eliminate taxes and scientists may even one day cheat death, but 'a' will always be 'a' and 5 will always be 5.

Comment: @Dinah: tongue in cheek, obviously. Nonetheless, it's incorrect to equate constants and literals. I don't think that a debate is particularly beneficial. That fact that you got four downvotes within the span of about a minute is probably evidence of that ;)

Comment: @Adam: noted, yet ironically, the identical humor got an equal number of upvotes in the same span and has yet to be downvoted. Baffling isn't it?

Comment: @Dinah: It is; but to say it hasn't been downvoted would be incorrect ;)

Comment: @Adam: I don't know what's worse, that you are trying to lead me down the same rabbit hole or that part of me *really* wants to go there anyway ;) must.... resist....

Comment: @Adam:  Not necessarily.  Case in point:  a FORTRAN programmer passed 1 to a function, which was passed to another function and changed there, changing the value of 1 throughout the program.  When he figured that out, he set something like ONE=1 (declaring ONE as integer, of course, since it's out of the I-N range), and everything worked fine.  His conclusion:  "Murphy was right.  Constants aren't, and variables won't."

Comment: @David: You're telling me that I can reassign the value of a literal in FORTRAN? I can say 1=2?